# Help me with understanding the solution of the following PDE system

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We have the following system of PDE:

$\textbf{The question:}$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta u = h \quad \text{for}\; (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^+ \\ 
u(x,0) = 0$$

Where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator

Where $h \in \mathbb{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R})$ such that $h_t(x) =^{def}h(x,t) = 0$ for $t < 0$.

$\textbf{The procedure to solve (this is what I need help with understanding):}$

First we write the system in spatial Fourier transformation:

$$\frac{\partial \hat{u}(\omega, t)}{dt} + ||\omega||^2\hat{u}(\omega,t) = \hat{h_t}(\omega) \\ \hat{u}(\omega, 0) = 0 $$

So I guess here we just use the normal definiton of $\mathbb{F}_{(1,1)}$

The homogeneous ode has solution:

$$\hat{u}_0(\omega, t) = A(\omega)\hat{\phi_t}(\omega)$$

Now we stipulate a particular inhomogeneous solution:

$$\hat{u}_p(\omega,t) = A(\omega,t)\hat{\phi}_t(\omega)$$

Substitution into the inhomogeneous ODE:

$\frac{dA(\omega,t)}{dt}\hat{\phi}_t(\omega) = \hat{h}_t{\omega}$

From this we obtain a solution for $A(\omega,t)$ in the form

$$A(\omega, t) = \int_{0}^t \hat{h}_{\tau}(\omega)\hat{\phi}_{- \tau}(\omega)$$

Because $\hat{u}_p$ fulfills the homogeneous i.c. we get:

$$\hat{u}(\omega, t) = \int_0^t \hat{h}_{\tau}(\omega)\hat{\phi}_{t-\tau}(\omega) d\tau$$

By using Fourier inversion we get:

$$u(x,t) = \int_0^t(h_\tau * \phi_{t- \tau})(x) d\tau = \int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h(\zeta,\tau)\phi(x - \zeta, t - \tau)d\zeta d\tau = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}h(\zeta, \tau) \theta(t- \tau) \phi(x - \zeta, t - \tau) d\zeta d\tau$$

Here * is the spatial convolution operator and $\theta$ is the indicator function.

============================================>

I need help with understanding the above procedure. Can somebody explain more in depth how we got to where we got?

Comment: Defining $h_t(\omega) = h(x,t)$ does not make sense because the left-hand-side depends on $(t,\omega)$ and the right-hand-side depends on $(x,t)$.

Comment: @Gonçalo It is Laplace: $h_{xx} + h_{tt}$

Comment: @Michael It should have been $h_t(x)$, my mistake